# Alignment of y axis labels and text

Tags: highcharts

I am having a problem with Highcharts y axis alignment with labels and text when there are more than one yAxis and opposite is true.

example 
http://jsfiddle.net/EuPwn/17/

Thanks in advance,

Sai

Answer (score 2):

So you have both yAxis on the right but on the same yAxis IDs. I would not do that, honestly. Why not an axis on the left and right? Or if you want both on the right still use 2 different IDs.
Something like this:
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes